# How do I run sumo-gui on instant-veins-4.7.1-i1.ova

Tags: python, omnet++, veins, sumo

I downloaded instant veins 4.7.1-i1 (a virtual appliance for running Veins) from the link below:

https://veins.car2x.org/download/instant-veins-4.7.1-i1.ova

But in my simulation, I need to run the `sumo-gui`, while the connection (`sumo-launchd.py`) in the virtualBox only runs the sumo. I tried to modify that a bit, 
but i can't.

Can you help me??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start the `sumo-launchd` with different parameters. The default configuration (shortcut in the "Activities" menu) executes the `sumo-launchd.py` with the `-vv` parameter.

```
/home/veins/src/veins/sumo-launchd.py -vv
```

To use `sumo-gui`, you can use the following command in a terminal:

```
python /home/veins/src/veins/sumo-launchd.py -vv -c sumo-gui
```